# Set and get variable specific to user in wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, session-variables

I am attempting to write a plugin for wordpress that partitions posts into different blocks, and then allows the user to access one block at a time. Right now I have it so I can get all the posts belonging to a block, set their block, etc.  However, I need to keep track of the ID of the block the user currently has chosen. My question is, how do I set a variable specific to a user session, and then how do I access it?

If more clarification is needed, ask and I will edit to explain.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using a php cookie. Here a link for noobs like me: http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_cookies.asp

Answer (score 0):

You may use session :-) or wordpress function [add_user_meta](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_user_meta)

Comment: I don't suppose you could elaborate? And user meta won't work because the block shouldn't remain from session to session; it should default to the most recent in a new session.

Comment: you still have an option to delete_user_meta at the end of session?

Comment: I want users to be able to do this even if they don't log in... I don't know if that would work...

Comment: I ended up just using a cookie.